# How to schedule an event in Mysql on table update?

Tags: mysql

I want to initiate an action after 7 days from the day a specific field in my database table is updated.

I can use trigger to trigger an event on update of field in the database table. But how can I make it wait for 7 days. I was looking for scheduling an Event but that can only be scheduled for specific  time. Is there any way to dynamically set the schedule time?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do it:

1. You store in a timestamp field when the record was last updated. You schedule a regular event to be run every couple of hours. The event's code scans the table in question and does whatever needs to be done for those records those timestamp is between the lust run of the even and the current time.

If you have lots of records you need to handle such events, then this is the recommended approach. The drawback is that timing of the event may not be fully accurate, depending on how often you schedule this event to run.

2. Every time you update the record you create an event specifically for that record in a trigger or stored procedure that triggers in 7 days time.

This approach gives you absolute accuracy over when an event is triggered, however, if you have a large number of changes, then this solution does not scale well.

An alternative solution could be to record the time when the change was done, but instead of event triggering base your code on user interaction. So, if the user, whose data has been updated logs on then you notify him about what you want regarding those updates that were done more than 7 days ago and the events were not seen by the user.